# How to mark an option as selected

Tags: themes, theme-options, options

I want to display post categories in theme settings, and I successfully did that using this code:

```
<?php /* Get the list of categories */ 
            $categories = get_categories();
            foreach ( $categories as $category) :
            $selected = ''; 
            ?>
<option <?php echo $option ?> value="<?php echo $category->cat_ID; ?>">
<?php echo $category->cat_name; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Everything is working fine and I'm able to call the option.

What is missing is that after I select a category, then I save the settings the category is not marked as selected within the drop down box. Yet the selected category is saved in the database.

--

I'm using acera theme options, and I edited the select type to create a select category option.

here is the code I started with:

```
<select name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>">
                        <?php
                        if (get_option($value['id']))
                            $default = get_option($value['id']);
                        else
                            $default = $value['default'];

                        foreach ($value['options'] as $option):
                            $selected = '';
                            if ($option == $default)
                                $selected = ' selected="selected"';
                            ?>
                            <option <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $option ?>

                            </option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>


                    </select>
```

So from this one I want to display the categories (I did this and the options are working in front end) and also to set the selected one as selected. (This is missing)

Thanks

Comment: What is `<?php echo $option ?>` supposed to do?

Comment: Thanks vancoder, I use acera theme options, I am not too much of coder but it was in the function to generate options for each type.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [`selected()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected).

Your updated `option` should look like this:

```
<option
    value="<?php echo $category->cat_ID; ?>"
    <?php selected($option, $category->cat_ID); ?>>
    <?php echo $category->cat_name; ?>
</option>
```

**// EDIT**
Oh, and BTW, in your particular case you might want to use the [`wp_dropdown_categories` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories), I guess.

That would be:

```
wp_dropdown_categories(
    array(
        'selected' => $option
        // maybe some other settings
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try it now, I really hope it works, you'll save my life.

Comment: it did not work, it showed the categories but they are out of the select, there is <option selected="selected" value=""> </option> out of the select. :(

Comment: I have edited my question by adding a useful detail, I really wish you guys can help me, I'm so thankful.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see my answer not working properly... Of course, you have to wrap the above code in a `select` tags - as I stated, it's just the `option` part. And, as @Shahinul Islam pointed out, you have to provide a value to be saved!

Comment: I am a newbie, I copied the code you gave me inside the select tags I have, and I used the wp_dropdown_categories instead of get_categories.. but it showed nothing.

The value that was saved is the cat_ID while the options in the back end show the cat_name.. everything was working except that the selected option is saved in database but if I refresh, the category is not selected. when I check its html code, I see no " selected=selected " .

Answer (score 1):

Please check your HTML code you don't give option's value : so when you store it will not saved.

```
<select name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>">
                    <?php
                    if (get_option($value['id']))
                        $default = get_option($value['id']);
                    else
                        $default = $value['default'];

                    foreach ($value['options'] as $option):
                        $selected = '';
                        if ($option == $default)
                            $selected = ' selected="selected"';
                        ?>
                        <option <?php echo $selected; ?> value="<?php echo $option ?>"><?php echo $option ?>

                        </option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>


                </select>
```

Comment: Thanks Shahinul, The code i and you sent back works fine, it's used to create a select type option. The value is created by the option array I use in the options page, I wanted to use it to create a select a category instead.